# How to implement hashtag view in Android?

Tags: android, hashtag

[image: hashtags view]

Any ideas how to implement this kind of view in Android **RelativeLayout**?
 Each of the hashtags should be a separate **TextView**.

Comment: you can make it with gridview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to write it, you can use [HashtagView](https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view) library for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `TableLayout` - `TableRow`(with textview as views), as you are gonna add tags in run time, you can decide how many `textview` needs to be added in a row, and add multiple rows.

Comment: can you please explain here for same like hashtag view as table layout ??

Comment: you have any example of add row  in table layout when button click as hastag ???